# Can an 'Abstract' parameter be passed to pandoc to create a latex file?

Tags: latex, pandoc

Similar to `$title$`, `$author$`, and `$date$`, is there an `$abstract$` parameter that one can pass to a latex file from the title block? Example:

```
\begin{abstract}
    $abstract$
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Also, in LaTeX, the `$` is used to enter/exit inline math, so if you want to define the text of the abstract somewhere else, it would be in the form of a macro: `\MyAbstract` instaed of `$abstract$`. Its definition would be something line `\newcommand{\MyAbstract}{This is the text of my abstract}`.

Comment: It's partly a latex question, mostly a pandoc question. Pandoc converts between various formats. Plus there are more pandoc questions here than there (the creator of pandoc replies frequently). I also asked at tex as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works fine (but no you don't need the `$` unless your abstract is for some reason in-line math)

```
\begin{abstract}
    This paper proposes a new method of blah blah blah
\end{abstract
```

Presumably with certain LaTeX templates it wouldn't work, but pandoc is smart enough to let most TeX markup through unhindered.